# Microsoft Access VBA - Importing data from an unnamed Word Form Field

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, ms-access-2010

I have been tasked with importing the contents of a Microsoft Word Form into my Access database. It's working fine using the following VBA code which is triggered from a form:

```
Private Sub cmdFileDialog_Click()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim objDialog As Object
    Dim varFile As Variant
    Dim rec, rec2 As Recordset
    Dim db As Database

    'New Word Document Variables
    Dim appWord As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    Const DEST_TABLE = "ap_behaviour_referrals" 'change to suit
    Const PATH_DELIM = "\"

    Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)
    ' Clear listbox contents.
    Me.fileList.RowSource = ""

With objDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    ' Set the title of the dialog box.
    .Title = "Please select a behaviour referral to import"
    ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Microsoft Word Forms", "*.docx"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No file selected."
    Else
        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
            'New docx Variable Actions
            Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
            Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(varFile)

        Next

        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rec = db.OpenRecordset(DEST_TABLE)

        With rec
            .AddNew
            ' my data
            'preformat the date fields from the form
            Dim unformattedpupildob As String
            Dim formattedpupildob As Date
            unformattedpupildob = doc.FormFields("Text2").Result
            unformattedpupildob = Replace(unformattedpupildob, ".", "/")
            formattedpupildob = Format(unformattedpupildob, "dd/mm/yy")
            'And now insert the record into the table
            !pupil_name = doc.FormFields("Text1").Result
            !pupil_dob = formattedpupildob
            !pupil_yr_grp = doc.FormFields("Text3").Result
            !pupil_submitted_eth = doc.FormFields("Text4").Result
            !pupil_upn = doc.FormFields("Text5").Result
            !pupil_looked_after = doc.FormFields("Text6").Result
            !sen_pre_statement = doc.FormFields("Text7").Result
            !sen_ehcp = doc.FormFields("Text8").Result
            !cat_date_final_ehcp = doc.FormFields("Text9").Result
            !num_exclusion = doc.FormFields("Text10").Result
            !days_exclusion = doc.FormFields("Text11").Result
            !sch_name = doc.FormFields("Text12").Result
            !sch_no = doc.FormFields("Text14").Result
            !contact_name = doc.FormFields("Text13").Result
            !contact_role = doc.FormFields("Text40").Result
            !contact_email = doc.FormFields("Text31").Result
            .Update
            .Close
            MsgBox "File Processing Complete"
        End With
    End If
End With
Set objDialog = Nothing
Me.fileList.RowSource = ""
ExitSub:
    Set rec = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    '...and set it to nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl() & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

All but one of the fields are (badly) bookmarked so I can use this to grab the contents of the field HOWEVER, I've come across an unnamed form field:

[image: Word Unnamed Form Field]

Which I need to import and I have no idea how to get the contents of it without a named bookmark.

I have no ability to modify the form since it's controlled by somebody else and is widely distributed, but was wondering if there was any way to pull the contents of this field without it being named?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other collections of objects, you can address them either by name (as you do for the other fields) or by numeric index.

```
For i = 1 To doc.FormFields.Count
    Debug.Print i, doc.FormFields(i).Result
Next i
```

This should give you the index of the field, if you know its content.

Then use `!the_answer = doc.FormFields(42).Result` in your code. (42 is an example!)

Edit: minimal working example (running in Access):

```
Public Sub TestWord()

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Long

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\foobar\Documents\Dok1.docx")
    oWord.Visible = True

    For i = 1 To oDoc.FormFields.Count
        Debug.Print i, oDoc.FormFields(i).Name, oDoc.FormFields(i).Result
    Next i

    oDoc.Close
    oWord.Quit

End Sub
```

The direct window (Ctrl+g) lists all form fields with their index, name = bookmark, and default text.

Comment: I've been trying various iterations of your code, but all I get is "Error #5941 was generated by Microsoft Word. The requested member of the collection does not exist."

I've tried changing the final part of the FormFields to a variety of different possibilities (Add, Application, Count, Creator, Item, Parent, Shaded are the allowable ones) but Word just doesn't seem keen to kick out any information about the fields and throws errors or doesn't tell me anything... I'm guessing Word just doesn't like being asked uncomfortable questions about its form fields!

Thanks for trying though!

Comment: OK, I *have* worked with Form fields (I knew that screen shot looked familiar). I didn't use the Document.FormFields collection, but addressed them directly via their bookmark. But if I open a document containing such fields, my code works fine. Which part exactly doesn't work for you? @TheAllPowerful

Comment: Problem was between my keyboard and my chair! I hadn't used the ctrl+g direct window before, and was expecting a debug report to pop up! My bad! As soon as I did that it all blazed into life, and I got the indexes all popped up for me! Thanks for your help! :-)